# How do I add a new user to a group with LDAP in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, ldap3

I'm trying to add a user to Active Directory via LDAP using Python 3 with ldap3.

Currently I have this line of code which works and returns true:

```
conn.add('cn=' + uid + ',cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com', 'user', {'sAMAccountName': uid, 'userPrincipalName': uid,'givenName': fname, 'sn': sname, 'displayName': name, 'mail': uid + '@example.com'})
```

All this does is simply create an user with the parameters given - great.

I then wanted to assign the user I'm creating to a group, so I added the following to the attribute list (also tried with `member` instead of `memberOf`):

```
'memberOf': ['cn=My Group,cn=Users,dc=example,dc=com']
```

But this returns false and does not create a user at all.

I assumed I had done something wrong so removed `memberOf`, ran the first lot of code again to recreate the user. I used the Active Directory Users and Computers tool on my Windows Server to manually add the group to the user. I opened IDLE, setup my connection and ran this (output cut for brevity):

```
>>> conn.search('dc=example,dc=com', '(objectclass=person)', attributes=['memberOf'])
>>> conn.entries
[...
, DN: CN=username,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: <snip>
    memberOf: CN=My Group,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
]
```

Which other than the caplitised `CN`  and `DC` was exactly what I had. I tried capitalising mine but it wouldn't work then either. This really puzzled me as I thought I was doing everything right. I've been Googling around and scratching my head for the last hour or two.

tl;dr How do you assign and AD group to an AD user upon creation using `Connection.add()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ldap3 library there is a specific method for adding users to one or more groups. Have a look at the `conn.extend.microsoft.add_members_to_groups(members, groups)` method.

Comment: Ah! Completely missed that. Thanks!